# Check if FibreChannel disk is mounted somewhere else

Tags: mount, lvm

I have two RHEL 6.5 servers. Each has access to the same FibreChannel LUN with multipathing and LVM on it – let's say `/dev/mapper/vg0-lv_shared`.

`lv_shared` can be mounted on server1 or server2
but not on both simultaneously.
I can't use cluster services so I am working on a simple script.

Is it possible to check from server1 if server2 has the `lv_shared` mounted in case there is no SSH connection between the servers?
In other words –
how can I check if disk available to server1 is mounted somewhere else?

Comment: I think you may not be able to do this check on server1. you can check it on the storage server itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly done via LVM tags (available since LVM2). Here is a short example to demonstrate them:

Assume you have a VG called "vg01" with 2 LVs "lvtest" and "lvother":

```
[root@centos ~]# lvs vg01
  LV      VG   Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lvother vg01 -wi------- 12.00m
  lvtest  vg01 -wi------- 12.00m
```

Now you enable LVM hosttags:

```
[root@centos ~]# grep ^tags /etc/lvm/lvm.conf
tags { hosttags = 1 }
```

And set a activation filter based on your hostname:

```
[root@centos ~]# cat /etc/lvm/lvm_centos.conf (centos.conf == hostname.conf)
activation { volume_list=["@centos"] }
```

Now let's check/set/del some tags:

```
[root@centos ~]# lvs vg01 -o +tags
 LV      VG   Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert LV Tags
 lvother vg01 -wi------- 12.00m
 lvtest  vg01 -wi------- 12.00m
```

Currently no tags are set (last column)

Activating the volume will not work:

```
[root@centos ~]# vgchange -ay /dev/vg01
 Not activating vg01/lvtest since it does not pass activation filter.
 Not activating vg01/lvother since it does not pass activation filter.
 0 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg01" now active
```

Let's add some tags and try again

```
[root@centos ~]# lvchange --addtag @centos /dev/vg01/lvtest
 Logical volume "lvtest" changed.

[root@centos ~]# lvchange --addtag @centos /dev/vg01/lvother
 Logical volume "lvother" changed.

[root@centos ~]# lvs vg01 -o +tags
 LV      VG   Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert LV Tags
 lvother vg01 -wi------- 12.00m                                              centos
 lvtest  vg01 -wi------- 12.00m                                              centos

[root@centos ~]# vgchange -ay /dev/vg01
 2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg01" now active
```

Better. ;-)

So in your case you should just set a tag on the `lv_shared` with the hostname of the server who should mount the LV.